# Is there any way to pass dynamic hours as a parameter in crone job in jankins cicd pipeline code

Tags: jenkins, cron, cicd

```kotlin
def random = new Random()
def randomHour = 7 + random.nextInt(3) // Generate a random number between 7 and 9
def randomMinute = random.nextInt(60) // Generate a random number between 0 and 59
println "randomHour: ${randomHour}"
println "randomMinute: ${randomMinute}"
jobProps << pipelineTriggers([parameterizedCron('\${randomMinute} \${randomHour} * * * %DEPLOY_TEST_ENVIRONMENT=true')])
```

I trying to run crone job any random time between 7:00AM to 9:00AM. I tryied with above way but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to avoid expanding the variables here?

```
jobProps << pipelineTriggers([parameterizedCron('\${randomMinute} \${randomHour} * * * %DEPLOY_TEST_ENVIRONMENT=true')])
```

I think expanding them should solve your problem

```
jobProps << pipelineTriggers([parameterizedCron("${randomMinute} ${randomHour} * * * %DEPLOY_TEST_ENVIRONMENT=true")])
```

You could also take advantage of [Jenkins hash syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#cron-syntax)

```
jobProps << pipelineTriggers([parameterizedCron('H H(7-9) * * * %DEPLOY_TEST_ENVIRONMENT=true')])
```

It does pretty much the same thing, except it doesn't change the scheduled time every run, it picks random time and after that it doesn't change.